# Under what conditions does Mathematica give a natural antiderivative when integrating?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Natural antiderivative is defined as follows, using Fourier transform:

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{- i \omega x}}{\omega} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega$$

Particularly, if $x=0$,

$$f^{(-1)}(0)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\omega} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega$$

Expressed as *Mathematica* code:

```
(I/Sqrt[2*Pi])*Integrate[(1/w)*FourierTransform[f[t], t, w], {w, -Infinity, Plus[Infinity]}]
```

That said, I wonder if *Mathematica* always adheres to the rule of providing the antiderivative which would satisfy this condition.

For instance, `Integrate[Sin[x], x]` gives `-Cos[x]`, which satisfies the condition as `-Cos[0] == -1`.

I wonder how much this rule is adhered to in the output of `Integrate`.

Answer (score 4):

Your equation has a sign error for the inverse Fourier transform. A simpler prescription is

```
I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[f[t], t, w]/w, w, x]
```

Although there is a lrge range of function for which this works, it will of course fail for all those functions for which the Fourier transform can't be calculated. Anyway, it does work for polynomials, e.g. as follows:

```
Table[
 Integrate[x^n, x] == 
  I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[t^n, t, w]/w, w, x], {n, 
  1, 10}]

(* ==> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

But an example for which `Integrate` works and the Fourier approach doesn't is this simple case:

```
I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[t^(1/2), t, w]/w, 
  w, x]

(*
==> I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[Sqrt[t], t, w]/w, 
  w, x]
*)
```

Comment: Are there cases when both integrate works, and the natural integral formula works but they give different results?

Comment: I have tried to correct the error. Is it correct now?

Comment: I found a function where there is difference by Eurer's Gamma constant: $\frac1{x-1}$

Comment: $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \sin  x & -(\cos  x) & -(\cos  x) \\
 \cos  x & \sin  x & \sin  x \\
 1 & x & x \\
 x & \frac{x^2}{2} & \frac{x^2}{2} \\
 x^2 & \frac{x^3}{3} & \frac{x^3}{3} \\
 e^{-x^2} & \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } (\text{erf} x) & \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi } (\text{erf} x) \\
 e^{-x^2} x & -\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2} & -\frac{e^{-x^2}}{2} \\
 \sin ^3 x & \frac{1}{12} (\cos  (3 x)-9 (\cos  x)) & \frac{1}{12} (\cos  (3 x)-9 (\cos  x)) \\
 \frac{1}{x-1} & \log  (x-1) & \log  \left| x-1\right| +\gamma  \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: But I think it is an error in FurierTransform function: taking the outer Furier transform by hand, gives zero in x=0, so normal integral function is more correct here. The same problem is with function 1/(x+1)

Comment: @Anixx I don't think it's a bug in the `1/(x-1)` case - it's a situation where the inverse Fourier transform involves a Cauchy principal-value integral (otherwise it's undefined). This seems to be a genuine counterexample to the thesis that all anti-derivatives of Fourier-transformable functions lead to the same unique choice of integration constants for both methods. I.e., the answer to your question is: there are no obvious general necessary and sufficient conditions that I would be able to formulate. But at least it works for many cases, including polynomials.

Comment: in both cases 1/(x+1) and 1/(x-1) if to take the outer Fourier transform by hand, one arrives to the value 0 in x=0. I wonder, why Mathematica calculates it defferently.