# How to create a reliable natural integral operator?

Tags: function-construction

Natural integral is one of the antiderivatives of a function, for which the integration conctant is fixed in a natural way.

It is defined as follows:

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{- i \omega x}}{\omega} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{i\omega t}dt \, d\omega = i\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(\frac1x \mathcal{F}(f(x))\right)$$

Formula in Mathematica:

```
FullSimplify[I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[f[t],t,w]/w,w,x]]
```

When this does not converge, the following formula serves as definition (again, when it converges):

$$f^{(-1)}(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom {-1}m \sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk(-1)^{m-k}f^{(k)}(x)$$

The first formula implemented in Mathematica usually gives result in closed form, while the second one does not (does anybody know how to implement it in Mathematica so that it to give expressions in closed form?).

Additionally the following rule applies regardless of whether the above-mentioned expressons converge (the first formula actually does not, the second one converges only for $0< a\le e, a\ne 1$):

$$(a^x)^{(-1)}=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}$$

Natural integral is linear operator for which all integration rules apply (such as integration by parts).

That said I want to know how can I construct an operator which would produce the natural integral for input function in closed form.

**UPDATE**

This is not a duplicate of the linked question because the linked question asks about behavior of Mathematica's function while this question asks how to construct a function. The questions are unrelated. Also the linked question does not have an answer.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this question is based on [an earlier question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58011/245) (and my answer to it). To explain what exactly makes this question different from that one, it would be good to show what *Mathematica* code you have already tried, and what your expected input and output looks like in some examples.

Comment: @Jens Actually the only formula that workds (in some cases) is the following: FullSimplify[I InverseFourierTransform[FourierTransform[f[t],t,w]/w,w,x]]. I do not see how can I implement the second formula in Mathematica so it to give closed-form results.

Comment: If a definition of a natural integral involves so many case distinctions, as in your question, then it is almost "by definition" not a natural definition. So in cases where the most general of your attempts doesn't work, you should just ask: why not simply use `Integrate`? By the way you forgot an $i$ on the right of the first equation.

Comment: @Jens Because "Integrate" is not guranteed to produce natural integral. It actually can produce arbitrary anti-derivative. See the linked question.

Comment: My point is simply this: `Integrate` takes your integrand and finds, if necessary, an appropriate transformation that allows the integral to be calculated. That may involve any number of transformations, among them potentially series (such as that on which your question relies). But it's important to realize that the choice of appropriate transformation is limited by the type of integrand, and there is no **one** transformation that could be used as a definition of **natural** for *all* integrands. In that sense, `Integrate` already finds **a reasonably natural** result.

Comment: @Jens Integrate does not give natural integral for all functions, for instance, Integrate[1/x, x] will produce Log[x] while the natural integral in this case is Log[Abs[x]]+EulerGamma.

Comment: @ anixx: are you sure that your second formula is correct? I can't see how x is produced by letting f(x) = 1. In fact f^(0) = 1, f^(1) = 0, f^(2) = 0, ..., and no x appears.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze the second formula does not converge for $f(x)=1$, but the first one does and gives $f^{(-1)}(x)=x$.

Comment: @ anixx: ok. Do you have an example where the second formula is applicable?

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze $f(x)=2^x$, $f(x)=e^x$, $f(x)=e^{x \cos a} \sin(x \sin a), 0\le a\le\pi/3$, $f(x)=x^2 e^x$, $f(x)=P(x) e^x$.

Comment: I voted to close as a duplicate originally, but it may be better to close because it's unclear what the question is asking. "Natural integral" is not a thing.

Comment: @Jens the question includes the definition, so what is unclear?

Comment: @ anixx: Thanks, I've checked the first three examples.

Comment: What's unclear is that the question gives three definitions and they do not in any obvious way agree with one another. Well, (1) and (3) seem to have nonoverlapping domains. Also I would suggest not using the term "natural" unless and until it is given a solid motivation/explanation.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Look here for a hint how the definitions may be related: http://mathoverflow.net/a/179218/10059

Comment: Thanks, that does indeed clarify the mystery of definition (2). I think there remains the issue of what exactly one can offer here. It is already seen that the FT approach can fail at the least on examples for which the FT does not exist. So I do not see a general way to extend the method you already have. Obviously there may be ad hoc approaches for various classes, e.g what you show for exponentials.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau is there a way to implement the second definition in Mathematica in such a way that it would produce results in a closed form (like the first formula does)?

Comment: You can always try to write that double sum, at least in such cases where you know a closed form for the kth derivative 9as a function of k). But even then I doubt the summation will evaluate to a closed form for complicated cases.

Comment: I have found a simpler formula for the antiderivative in the second format: In fact, writing 1/u = 1/(1-(1-u)) = Sum[(1-u)^m,{m,0,inf}], and expanding (1-u)^m = Sum[Binomial[m,k] (-u)^k,{k,0,m}] we obtain for u->d/dx : f^(-1)(x) = Sum[Sum[Binomial[m,k] (-1)^k D[f[x],{x,k}],{k,0,m}],{m,0,inf}]. In applying it the term m=0 should be trated separately. My question (especially to Daniel): is this kind of treatment of antiderivatives common knowledge. If so, where can I find more information?

Comment: @ Anixx. As I said, m=0 should be treated separately. This is because otherwise MMA gives zero for f[x] = Exp[x]. The term m=0 simply gives f[x]. My formula is simpler because it has just one binomial coefficient instead of two. But the formulas coincide! Just simplify your formula: Binomial[-1,m] -> (-1)^m.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze yes, it is possible to simplify it this way. One can also use $$f^{(-1)}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom {-1}n\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{s-n}{s-k}\binom nk(-1)^{n-k}f^{(k)}(x)$$ or $$f^{(-1)}(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k f^{(k)}(x)}{(-1-k)k!(n-k)!}}{\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{(-1)^k }{(-1-k) k!(n-k)!}}$$ with a benefit of the leter formula in that it can be adapted to cases when particular derivative in a point becomes infinite.

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze That approach looks like something that would need to be applied in a Fourier transform setting (as we sort of have in this thread). Else I don't see how multiplicative inverse and operator inverse (of derivative) will be related. For what it's worth, I tried this on `f[x_]=x` and came up nowhere near `x^2`. But I may have done the summation incorrectly.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau the second formula diverges for f(x)=x. You can see some functions for which it works in my reply to Dr. Wolfgang Hintze above.

Comment: I would expect that maybe a regularization would recover the desired result. Seems not to do so.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau no, it won't, 1st derivative is non-zero, all others are zero. Newton series will not converge for such function. That's why Fourier method is used. But the question is how to obtain the functions in closed form.

Comment: I realize the series won't converge. That's why I was anticipating a regularization might work. The only one that gave a result, `"Dirichlet"`, gave a linear rather than x^2-plus-constant.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau that's why my incidential discovery of the Fourier formula is so valuable (it can find natural integral even for Dirac Delta and sgn(x)) http://math.stackexchange.com/a/906379/2513 I wonder whether it is easier to polish the Fourier formula. For instance, why it works for sine and cosine but does not for hyperbolic functions? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It works for sine but not sinh for the obvious reason that the former has a Fourier transform whereas the latter does not. I think that's been stated a few times in some of the related threads.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau well, exponent HAS a formal Fourier transform, $$\mathcal{F}[e^{ax}]=\delta(x-\frac a{2\pi i})$$ So I wonder, if it is possible to make Mathematica to know it?

Comment: (1) This question ahs been closed. We're spending way too much on a closed question. (2) For real `a` that formal definition is not likely to be of much use. Divide it by `x` and take the IFT. You get zero (because you integrate over R and the delta "spike" is off R). (3) Time to move on to other things.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau what if Fourier integral in taken over whole complex plane?